# Is there way to change point color in chart using achartengine android

Tags: android, colors, point, achartengine

Hello I'm novice to android.
I'm developing app now with achartengine to draw chart~
now I have problem with that some point on the line graph must change color not everything point on the line and line.

I think it should be extended parent class(GraphicalView) but this ways make me crazy~
now I asking android developer experienced.

plz help me~

Comment: can you please post your efforts ?

Answer (score 0):

Okz i was working with `AChart` library it is fully customizable you can change color of any thing in your chart for example if you are using its Example `AverageTemperatureChart` you will see an object renderer which hold properties how a chart will be render there are several set property methods like `setTitle` `setTitleColor` etc you can use that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want some points of the graph line and a part of the line to change color. The simplest way I can think about to do it is to plot another line and/or a set of points on top of the existing line with different color. The code to do so would be:

```
    // your existing chartView, dataset, and renderer
    GraphicalView mChartView;
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(2);

    // new series, to plot it with different color
    XYSeries newXYSeries = new XYSeries("");
    XYSeriesRenderer newXYSeriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

    newXYSeries.add(0, 0); // add the points you want the color to be different
    newXYSeriesRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK); // set color

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(newXYSeriesRenderer);
    mDataset.addSeries(newXYSeries);

    // you might want to set the range to make sure that the lines are plotted on top of each other
    // not sure if it is necessary 
    mRenderer.setRange(new double[] { MIN_X, MAX_X, MIN_Y, MA_Y });
```

I think that's about it. You need to add to the newXYSeries all the points you want the color to be different.